# Are the noun and verb forms of "badger" related etymologically?

Tags: etymology, homonyms

Are the noun "badger", naming an animal, and the verb "to badger", describing the behavior of a person, related etymologically? Does the meaning of one come directly from the other?

What about the word "badge"?

Comment: added you tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[the verb is actually derived from the noun](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=badger), here's the noun:

> 1520s, from M.E. bageard, perhaps from
>   bage "badge" + -ard "one who carries
>   some action or possesses some
>   quality," suffix related to M.H.G.
>   -hart "bold" (see -ard). If so, the central notion is the badge-like white
>   blaze on the animal's forehead (cf.
>   Fr. blaireau "badger," from O.Fr.
>   blarel, from bler "marked with a white
>   spot"). But blaze (2) was the usual
>   word for this. An O.E. name for the
>   creature was the Celtic borrowing
>   brock; also græg (M.E. grei, grey). In
>   Amer.Eng., the nickname of inhabitants
>   or natives of Wisconsin (1833).

and here's the verb (refers to noun):

> 1794, from badger (n.), based on the
>   behavior of the dogs in the medieval
>   sport of badger-baiting. Related:
>   Badgered; badgering.

Comment: That's very interesting that the verb is not from the action of the animal itself, but that of another creature _towards_ the animal. Oh, and the animal is named after the item "badge". Thanks!

Comment: @Josh Caswell that's a good observation! I guess you can't badger by yourself! :)

Answer (score 6):

The verb *badger*, as with *dog*, *ferret*, *weasel*, *bug*, *ram*, *hog*, *slug*, *crow*, *crab*, *parrot*, *squirrel*, *porpoise*, *bull*, and *buffalo*, comes from the (alleged) behavior or treatment of the animal (as do *pig out*, *monkey with*, *horse around*, *rat out*, *outfox*, and *cat about*).  Hunting for a particular animal gets its name from *mouse*, *whale*, *fish*, and (less commonly) *moth*, *owl*, and *bird*.

The same is *not* true of *cow*, *grouse*, and *quail*, and (less surprisingly) *swallow*, *sow*, and *bear* — the animal and the verb are etymologically unrelated.

The only common animal name that I found that comes the other way is *sloth* (the animal was named after the sin), but I'm on the look-out for more.  (In *Silence Of The Lambs* a character claims that "moth" originally meant "to destroy", but I can't find a cite.)

The verb *butterfly* is a culinary term meaning to cut something open, so it (vaguely) resembles a butterfly, said of mostly shrimp and chicken breast.  It's the only example I have found of an animal name meaning "to make resemble the animal", unless you count *spread-eagle*.

Comment: Great background info!

Answer (score 1):

This happens to be my last name so when I was researching my families geneology I learned that it also means "peddler" someone who sold wares from a cart. It is also used to annoy,be bothersome or abusive-  "Don't badger the witness" You wouldn't ever want to corner one, they can be quite nasty.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer is interesting, but could be strengthened by citing an authoritative reference that supports it. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.