# Is analog (adjective) related to analog (noun)?

Tags: etymology

*analog* (adjective) is a continuous stream; it's not digital.

*analog* (noun) is a comparison, two subjects may be analogous.

Do they share etymology? Is there another reason why those concepts use the same word? To my understanding, the meanings are quite different.

Comment: Yes, they do. An analog device operates by using a property that corresponds to (is analogous to) the phenomena of interest. For example, analog watches (the wind-up type) use the correspondence between the movement of the internal mechanisms and the time it takes for those physical movements to occur. Analog recording might make the depth of a groove correspond to the volume (or pitch) of the recorded sound.

Comment: (I'm placing the above answer in comments because I'm not certain that this is strictly-speaking a question about the English language. However, it is certainly an interesting question.)

Comment: Lawrence - that is one of the **best things I have ever read on the site**.  I've struggled for years to see the relationship between the two meanings of analog.  Cheers for that.

Comment: The term "analog", as used in electronics, refers to having voltages/currents which are in proportion to some other metric.  While "analog" is used to mean "not digital", that is not what it actually means.  (And, of course, "digital" doesn't mean what you think it means either.)

Comment: Lawrence: If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it. If it ends up being considered off topic, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Lawrence: May I ask why this question is off-topic? Both words are english words. Is it that this site is only for explaining the meaning of words, but not their history?

I guess the question could be formulated as "Do the english words analog (noun) and analog (adjective) describe the same phenomenon". Would this still be off topic?

Is [this similar question on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/are-the-noun-and-verb-forms-of-badger-related-etymologically?rq=1)?

Comment: @Teodor I just saw your comment (use "@" to more reliably ping the user). I didn't vote to close the question. On reflection, this is probably just as valid an etymology question as any other. The reason that tchrist gave for closing your question was for lack of research. Research on Stack Exchange is defined quite broadly, but high-traffic communities such as EL&U often require some proof of having 'done your homework'. Try adding a quote + link from [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=analogue), and a [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/analogue).

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks! Given the interest, I'll post an answer if this question is reopened. (Sorry for the late reply - I only saw your comment after getting Teodor's ping.)

Comment: @Teodor Ping me if the question is reopened, and I'll post an answer. Once you [edit] your question, it automatically comes up for review for reopening. To speed up the process, post a 'question' on [Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/) *after* the edit, to request reopening the question. [Here's an example of such a request.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7793/142322) The main thing to note is to address the stated reason for closure, and in particular, what you've done to address it. Once the objections are sufficiently addressed, the community tends to support reopening.

Comment: @Teodor *"May I ask why this question is off-topic?"* voting on this site is well-known to be just totally bizarre and random. It's the "quirky site".  For better or worse, completely random unexplainable things happen voting wise and close/open wise here. So don't worry about it.  Again, this is literally one of the, say, 30 best questions *ever posted here*.